# Why doesn't code in `@async` run as expected with `println`?

Tags: multithreading, julia

When I run the following code, it runs as expected (that is, it outputs both "endless loop" and "loop in 100"):

```
@async while true
print("endless loop\n")
end
for i in 1:100
print("loop in 100\n")
end
```

However, for some reason, when I changed `print` to `println`, the result was very different

```
@async while true
println("endless loop")
end
for i in 1:100
println("loop in 100")
end
```

This code only outputs "loop in 100" a hundred times. Any ideas why?

Actually, `println` seems to **always** impact multithread execution:

```
## works as expected, prints "loop in 100" 100 times and "endless loop" 3 times in between
@async while true
print("endless loop\n")
end
@sync for i in 1:100
@async print("loop in 100\n")
end
## simply switching to println makes a program that outputs "endless loop" forever
@async while true
println("endless loop")
end
@sync for i in 1:100
@async println("loop in 100")
end
```

I used `println` for debug output but then realised it's unusable for that purposes. Any suggestion why exactly this works the way it works would be very helpful. I'm executing it with Julia 1.6.1 so that I can use automatic thread detection `julia -t auto file.jl`.

Comment: I'm only guessing, but maybe because the multi-argument `print` [calls `lock` on `io` twice](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/1b93d53fc4bb59350ada898038ed4de2994cce33/base/strings/io.jl#L54-L72)?

Comment: Just a guess: might have to do with `print` being buffered while `println` flushes after every call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `println` [implementation](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/1b93d53fc4bb59350ada898038ed4de2994cce33/base/strings/io.jl) for julia 1.6.1 includes nested `lock` calls:

```
println(io::IO, xs...) = print(io, xs..., "\n")

function print(io::IO, xs...)
    lock(io)
    try
        for x in xs
            print(io, x)
        end
    finally
        unlock(io)
    end
    return nothing
end

function print(io::IO, x)
    lock(io)
    try
        show(io, x)
    finally
        unlock(io)
    end
    return nothing
end
```

In your simplified example this implementation has a side effect on the order of task scheduling.

Compare `test1.jl` using `println`:

```
t = @async for i in 1:3
    println("endless loop")
end

for i in 1:3
    println("loop in 100")
end

wait(t)

$ julia test1.jl 
loop in 100
loop in 100
loop in 100
endless loop
endless loop
endless loop
```

With `test2.jl` using `print`:

```
t = @async for i in 1:3
    print("endless loop\n")
end

for i in 1:3
    print("loop in 100\n")
end

wait(t)


$ julia test2.jl 
loop in 100
endless loop
loop in 100
endless loop
loop in 100
endless loop
```

Note that the async task should be awaited otherwise the process exits without giving a chance to run the async task.

But the "perturbing" effect of `println` on task scheduling disappear
when the tasks block and yield controls to the scheduler, as in real world scenario, simulated in`test3.jl`
with a `sleep`:

```
t = @async for i in 1:3
    println("endless loop")
    sleep(1)
end

for i in 1:3
    println("loop in 100")
    sleep(1)
end

wait(t)


$ julia test3.jl 
    loop in 100
    endless loop
    loop in 100
    endless loop
    loop in 100
    endless loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Clearly `println()` behaves differently from `print`, and likes to finish before it allows other tasks printing.  You could write the \n into the `print()` yourself though:

```
@async while true
    print("endless loop\n")
end
for i in 1:100
    print("loop in 100\n")
end
```

if you really need the interleaving between threaded `print`s.